# Deleting/Renaming a locked file

Tags: php, file, delete-file, file-rename

With PHP, is there a way to force unlock a file (for renaming/deleting) that is locked by another running program on the same server?

More details:
I have an image service running on the server that caches really large pathology images for the web but when I try to delete or rename images through a PHP interface, I cannot do so when the image files are locked and still being accessed by the web image service.

I have no control over the web service so I cannot tell it to close the image. A work around is to simply restart the web service and then delete/rename the files but that would cause a service interruption for other users trying to access other images through the web.

OS: Windows Server 2003

Comment: It's running on Win Server 2003. In this case, the image service is not modifying the images, just reading tiles out of large tiffs. The service is probably doing a write lock for no reason but it's a commercial product so I can't modify it. Is it still not safe to force unlock the images?

Comment: Philosophy won't work here. Technical solutions for the situation only help. How to release the lock for delete? Is there an option to force release to delete the file or rename?